# The time complexity of this algorithm finding prefix

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

This algorithm i wrote to check whether one string is a prefix for another string in    the array. 
    The complexity is O(n*(n-1)*k), where n is the number of strings in the array, 
    and K is the largest length of the string. Am I right here in complexity analysis?

```
public static void isPrefix(String[] strs){

    for(int i=0; i<strs.length; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<strs.length; j++){
            String a = strs[i];
            String b = strs[j];

            if(!commonStr(a,b).isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(a + "->" + b);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static String commonStr(String a, String b){
    int smaller = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
    for(int k=0; k<smaller; k++){
        if(a.charAt(k) != b.charAt(k)){
            return "";
        }
    }
    return a.substring(0,smaller);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] strs = {"ab", "abc", "cde", "abef"};
    isPrefix(strs);
}
```

Comment: Might be a stupid question (and totally off topic), but why not use startsWith?

Comment: If you add or remove words from your array and want to check for prefixes lots of time, maybe you should consider using another data structure, a Trie for example : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Yes, tries is better, but for BigO analysis only

Comment: startsWith is good, but here just want to write the algorithm and analyze.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, I believe. It's just that K is not exactly 
that. But roughly speaking it's OK to say so.

Also it is `K * n * (n-1) / 2` as you don't inspect all
ordered couples of strings (you inspect only half of them).
In your example, you inspect 6 couples, not 12.

Note that if your strings are say between 1 million and 2 million chars long,
but your n is just say 20 or 50 or 100, then K prevails and this estimate
is to be interpreted with care. Typically one would expect n >> K though,
I guess that's what you had in mind too.

Comment: Why do you say inspecting only half? The half is on average? The worst case should be K * n^2?

Comment: The half is OK. You don't need to inspect (strs[1], strs[0]) provided you already did so for (strs[0], strs[1]).